# iOS flickers in iscroll (web)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, mobile-safari

If the size of the iscroll block exceeds a particular limit in iphone safari,it starts flickering on opening that tab again.I solved it by spliting into sub blocks.but what is the reason for the flickers?and is there any alternative solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

this might solve the problem:

```
#scroller * {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

I had the same problem and found a solution here:
https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/168

Cheers

Comment: Applying 3d property to child nodes may be a solution.but my question was if a block is single element(exceeds particular limit) with no child.how can we prevent flickering?